# qemu - Scrollback in the monitor console

Tags: scrolling, qemu

How can I scroll back in the monitor (compat_monitor0) in SDL and GTK views? I somewhere found it can be done with Ctrl+PgUp, but that does not work.

Answer (score 3):

In GTK the monitor runs in a vte terminal widget so the standard Shift+PgUp works like it does in most terminal emulator apps.

In SDL there is no scrollback support.

Comment: Shift+PgUp does not work in my build when I set `-display gtk`.

Comment: Probably your machine lacks the vte devel package then, so qemu was compiled without vte terminal support.

Comment: Yes I do not have vte package. I am going to recompile qemu and try it.